# Capturando elementos por tag e inserindo dentro de um array

Tags: javascript, array

Bom, estou montando um carrossel em um projeto teste, e me surgiu uma dúvida, como posso, com `vanillaJS`, capturar determinados elementos pela `tag`, e colocá-los dentro de um `array` ? A ideia seria mais precisamente, capturar de acordo com a posição no corpo do `HTML`, por exemplo;capturar todos os `figure` que estão dentro de uma `div` cujo o pai é #banners.

Como posso fazer isso ao carregar a página ?

Comment: Poderia adicionar o código?

Comment: não tem um código pronto, o array seria o meu primeiro passo, só esquematizei em papel mesmo :D

Comment: tenho só o html, mas seria como o próprio exemplo dado, não teria nada de diferente msm

Comment: Tenta assim: var arr = document.querySelectorAll("#banners figure");

Comment: Entendi, mais poste por favor, vai ajudar bastante

Comment: perfeito @JuniorNunes

Comment: posta código como resposta man :D

Comment: Beleza, vou responder então.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o `document.querySelectorAll`, assim:

```
var arr = document.querySelectorAll("#banners figure")
```